# Put codenameon one Tab selectedIndex at the first position

Tags: java, indexing, tabs, codenameone, selectedindex

I am working on a program and then I need to have the selected index of my tab a the first position.

Look at this picture:

[image]

Now what I want is the tab "today" need to be displayed right at the beginning.

How can I do that?
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you tell us what language your program is in, and show us the code you have so far? Use the [edit] button to improve your question.

Comment: I am using java with codename one framework

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the previous tabs from the `Tabs` control and then Today would be "first" but I'm guessing you just want `Today` to be at the left most position and not the first position.

That might be a bit challenging as there is no standard API for that. You might be able to manipulate the `setScrollX` value to match the value of the `getX` on `Today` but that is a pretty big hack...

Comment: Thanks Shai, exactly i just want Today to be at the left most position and not the first position. I am going to test it and let you know

Comment: I just try, but first i am not seing any setScrollX method, i just see setX et getX method for the Tabs class, can you tell a little more about the process i must take to have that effect?

Comment: And can we control the number of tab to be displayed once, for example i want to have 3 tabs visible, cause i am seing that some tab are cut off, is that possible too?

Comment: It's protected, you might need to derive container in some way. I'm not sure if this is something you can do easily... Since the tabs are scrollable and might have varying lengths you don't really have control over that. It sounds to me you might want to create your own component, just use the methods to hide the "tabs" in the `Tabs` component and then place your own UI to represent the tabs on top.